# My app not connecting to MIKROS Analytics

Tags: mikros, mikros-analytics, mikros-game-analytics

I created an app on MIKROS analytics and it was approved. I have my "appGameId" and "apiKey" but my app still says

> Not connected. Click here to begin

Clicking on the link only takes me to the Insights section. How do I get my app connected?

Comment: Are you affiliated with the MIKROS product? If so, is your affiliation mentioned in any of your relevant questions and answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you have to initialize the MIKROS SDK inside of your project.

Official Documentation:
https://developer.tatumgames.com/documentation/getting-started

Integration Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g380D_bAVA

The full instructions are as follows:

1. Download the MIKROS SDK: https://developer.tatumgames.com/documentation/downloads
2. In the Unity editor, select Assets > Import Package > Custom Package. Navigate to the directory where you downloaded the MIKROS SDK and select the unitypackage
3. Import the assets in the package.
4. In the Inspector tab of MIKROS Settings, add your generated AppGameID and API Keys. You also have the option to edit other relevant settings from here.

Select auto initialize MIKROS SDK or manually initialize the SDK at app start with

```
MikrosManager.Instance.InitializeMikrosSDK();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to initialize the MIKROS SDK inside of your project.
Here's a full tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g380D_bAVA

You can choose to auto-initialize the SDK, or use this code to do it manually:

```
MikrosManager.Instance.InitializeMikrosSDK();
```